# C# SOAP client exception empty response

Tags: asp.net, webservice-client

I am trying to get XML data from NDFDXMl from WebService from http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl . I have added the service and created form application. I am getting an exception :

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Services.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The request failed with an empty response.
Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WeatherServiceReference.ndfdXML myweather = new WeatherServiceReference.ndfdXML();
    WeatherServiceReference.weatherParametersType wtp = new WeatherServiceReference.weatherParametersType();
    wtp.temp = true;
    decimal lat = 32.7452M;
    decimal lng = -117.1979M;

    String response = myweather.NDFDgen(lat, lng , WeatherServiceReference.productType.timeseries, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, WeatherServiceReference.unitType.e, wtp);

    response = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("Tempurature"));
    lbl_results.Text = response;

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Use a try- catch block for making the service call and see what exception you are receiving.

Comment: Getting Empty response

Comment: I'm having the same issue in one of my applications, for me it seems to be that .net isn't parsing the xml correctly, i used fiddler and the response shows the data coming in, if you find a solution could you post it here? I will try to answer this question if i find anything in my side